# Anchor or Button in React SPA?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-router, accessibility

Say there is piece of text (regardless of whether it is styled as a "traditional" link or button) on a page that when clicked leads to a new page with a new page/URL. But the navigation happens programmatically (e.g. via `react-router` using the History web API) instead of a hard HTTP refresh.

In this case, should it be a traditional anchor link with `href` attribute such as `#` or a button?

**Option 1**:

```
<a href="#" onClick={navigateToNextPage}>Link</a>
```

The downside is that you have a junk `href` attribute. You could remove that but then it is not in the tab order and doesn't get default link styling (though these could be overcome with one-off styling). Also if you copy the link it will copy as `#` which is incorrect and be interpreted incorrectly by screen readers.

**Option 2**:

```
<button onClick={navigateToNextPage}>Link</a>
```

The downside here is that if you want it to look like a traditional link you need to apply custom styling. Also in some ways it is really acting like a traditional link in my view. But this would be better for screen readers.

Comment: Use either `history.push()` or `<Link to='' >Link</Link>` . The Link will translate into `<a>` but will not do a "hard refresh:

Comment: @Enchew right now I am using `history.push()` but then what to put in the anchor tag for `href` attribute? Now it is not very accessible either.

Comment: I mean to use `history.push()` on a button, but if you want <a> tag, use the `<Link>` Component from 'react-router-dom', instead of pure <a>

Comment: @Enchew should buttons be used for page/URL navigation, though?

Comment: Sometimes they are needed - for example if you want to execute an ajax call and then redirect the user, or save something in the state, or any action in general. If you want simple navigation, I advise you to use `<Link>`

Comment: @Enchew unfortunately it is some extra behavior, followed by a navigation, not simply a navigation. But using a custom anchor tag instead of `Link` is really just the same thing.

Comment: `<a href="" ...>` or `<a href ...>` should work. If it directs/refreshes, you may use `event.preventDefault()` inside its `onClick` method.

Comment: @RiteshJagga it works but now you have an anchor with a junk value for `href` which isn't great from accessibility perspective.

Comment: `href=""` is a valid and acceptable value. Additionally, it is used so that anchor can have focus, without this attribute you'll need to use `tabindex="0"`.


As far as accessibility is concerned, we have several places where we used this method and it passes accessibility auto and manual checks.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I can't comment on React but here is the correct method for SPAs, implementing it should be trivial in React.

### Short Answer

Use a hyperlink (`<a>`) to navigate between pages and when loading additional content if no other option is available.

More simply: if the URL changes or you add large amounts of information to the page, use a hyperlink.

### Long Answer

In your question you mentioned the History API and `react-router`.

For this reason I assume that the function `navigateToNextPage` changes the URL.

I also assume that I could access that page directly if I desired by entering that URL into my browser.

With those assumptions in mind you should use:-

```
<a href="new-page-url" onClick={navigateToNextPage}>Link</a>
```

Obviously you would stop the default action (`e.preventDefault()` or React equivalent).

A couple of points on **why** to use the format described above:-

1. **Accessibility** - when I encounter a hyperlink with a screen reader I am able to ask my screen reader where that link will take me, this is reassuring, I can't do the same with a button. **This is why I didn't use `#` for the hyperlink but instead added the actual destination. If you see `href="#"` it is nearly always a sign that the wrong element is being used or it is being used incorrectly. After reading your comments about performing an action before navigating this is still perfectly valid, perform your action and then redirect, it is still navigation at the end of the day.**
2. **Accessibility** - when I am navigating a site via a screen reader I may decide to cycle through all the hyperlinks on the page to get a feeling for the page structure. (<kbd>NVDA modifier</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> to get next link for example). I am very unlikely to loop through all the buttons on a page to look for navigation.
3. **Accessibility** - If I encounter a link I *expect* the page to change (even via AJAX). If I encounter a button I expect it to *perform an action on the current page*. Expected behaviour is a key part of accessibility.
4. **Accessibility** - hyperlinks have some important states. 'visited' is a key one on pages with lots of links as I may want to review something I read earlier and being able to navigate via visited links (e.g. <kbd>NVDA modifier</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd> for all unvisited links). Buttons do not expose this information. An important point here is that you also can't style a button with `button:visited` in your CSS so you miss out on the visual clue for everybody there.
5. **Accessibility** - <kbd>Space</kbd> key vs the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key. If I land on a link I am expecting to press `space` to navigate, a `<button>` only works with the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key and so I may be confused as to why the page isn't changing. (I am assuming at this point you have used a load of `aria` to convince me this button is a hyperlink).
6. **Robustness** - If your site has limited functionality *when* JavaScript fails a hyperlink is far better than a button. It will still work *when* JavaScript fails and this is especially useful *when* a JavaScript failure may only be a temporary load problem with one page, allowing a user to get to another functioning page.
7. **SEO** - I dare to speak of SEO on Stack Overflow? Shame! Shame! Shame! :-P - but seriously although Google is pretty darned smart in what it can do on JS powered sites it does still struggle to work out where a JavaScript only link will take it. If SEO matters for you then use a hyperlink with a valid destination so Google can map information correctly.

Probably other reasons I have forgotten to mention but I think I have made the point.

#### What do you have to consider when using AJAX to navigate between pages?

Although not part of your question I thought I would quickly add a couple of points for completeness.

You need to signal to a user that a page is loading if you are using a SPA pattern (and therefore interrupting normal navigation). e.g. I click your link you need to let me know that an action is being performed (loading.....) as you intercept the normal browser behaviour with `e.preventDefault()` or equivalent.

The simplest way is to use [`aria-live=assertive`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Live_Regions) on a region that explains the page is loading. You can Google how to implement that correctly.

Additionally when the new page loads you need to manage focus.

The best way to do this is to add a level 1 heading (`<h1>`) to each page that has `tabindex="-1"`.

Once the page loads the last action you perform in your JavaScript navigation function is to place the focus onto this heading.

This has two benefits:

1. it lets the user know where they are now
2. it also lets them know when the page load is complete (as AJAX navigation doesn't announce when the page is loaded in most screen readers).

By using `tabindex="-1"` it means that the heading won't be focusable by anything other than your JavaScript so won't interfere with the normal document flow.

Comment: Love your answer.

Comment: Love love love it! Exactly what I was looking for - thank you!

Comment: Not a problem, glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

You can just do `e.preventDefault()` when clicked on `<NavLink>` do your thing. Then navigate. `NavLink` generates `<a>` tag in HTML and provide `active` class by default when route is active. This allow you to style active state link.

```
import React from "react";
import { NavLink, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";

function Header(props) {
  const handleClick = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("DO SOMETHING");
    props.history.push(e.target.pathname);
  };
  return (
    <ul>
      <li>
        <NavLink exact to="/" onClick={handleClick}>
          Home
        </NavLink>
      </li>
      <li>
        <NavLink to="/about" onClick={handleClick}>
          About
        </NavLink>
      </li>
      <li>
        <NavLink to="/topics" onClick={handleClick}>
          NavLink
        </NavLink>
      </li>
    </ul>
  );
}

export const HeaderNav = withRouter(Header);
```

Wokring example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-router-5-rqzqq

Comment: I don't understand the reason for the downvote. It solves the problem?

Comment: I think you got a downvote as it doesn't answer whether to use a button or a hyperlink. Seems a bit harsh to me as someone could have just commented this to let you fix it.

Comment: That seems to be only explanation. If it's the reason its not just harsh it's a n00b thing to do. With `<NavLink>` generates `<a>` in HTML and includes `active` class when in that route which allow you to style as you want. I've provided working example ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score -3):

I would recommend you to use semantic HTML. This means using the correct HTML elements for their intended purpose as much as possible.

> 1. Easier to develop with — you can get some functionality for     free, plus it is arguably easier to understand.
> 2. Better on mobile — semantic HTML is arguably lighter in file size than non-semantic spaghetti code, and easier to make responsive.
> 3. Good for SEO — search engines give more importance to keywords inside headings, links, etc., than keywords included in non-semantic
>      s, etc., so your documents will be more findable by customers.

There's [more details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Accessibility/HTML)