# Page Navigation not working on Button Click

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have no idea why React Router won't work when I try navigating to the `/addData` component upon the click of a button. It works as it should when I try with the path but not when I click the button. I would like to know what I'm doing wrong. Please note, this is my first time with React Router. The version of React Router I'm using is `react-router-dom": "^5.3.0`
Here is the code.

App.js

```
import MainScreen from "./screens/main_screen/main_screen";
import AddDataScreen from "./screens/add_data/add_data";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={MainScreen}>
          </Route>
          <Route path="/addData" component={AddDataScreen}>  //This is a blank page with Add Data written on it
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The component where the button is from which I intend to navigate:

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const FloatingButton = () => {

    const addScreen = () => {
        <Link to="/addData">Add Data</Link>
        console.log("Clicked")
    }

    return (
        <div className="floatingButton">
            
            <div className="addFloat" onClick={addScreen}>   //The button
                <IoMdAdd color={"white"} size={"20px"}/>
            </div>
            
        </div>
    );
}

export default FloatingButton;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `addScreen` function just returns `Link` which is a component, and this approach does not call any redirecting action (as you can see [here](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/basic), Link results in an `<a>` element).

You could use the `useHistory` hook to access the `history` object and push the `addData` route:

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

  let history = useHistory();

  const addScreen = () => {
    history.push("/addData");
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My question now is, when do we use Links to navigate between pages?

Comment: This is mainly for semantic reasons. Using a `button` element to redirect users is semantically incorrect as you're supposed to use `a` for that. This answer has a more detailed explanation if you're interested: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64443954

Comment: It's been updated on `react-router-dom` v6 to `useNavigate()`. 

Use as follows: `const navigate = useNavigate(); navigate("/home");`